# Integration services catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I was trying to create integration catalog in 2018 SSMS as shown in some videos on youtube it is a easy process. But whenever I click on create SSISIR it takes me to another wizard SSIS in ADF configuration. Although I have an Azure subscription as well and created a database in Azure. But still I am not able to get catalog server end point in this wizard. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From SSMS, you can create the catalog locally or you can create a SSIS-IR on Azure. One is the on-premise story vs the other is cloud. which one do you prefer?

I guess you go the the cloud story.